# Unhandled error event occurred while using ttf font file in React JS

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I've been using this MYFONT.ttf in my React Project for a long time. But suddenly it's throwing the following error when I try to `yarn start` the project.

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/public/fonts/MYFONT.ttf ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/kbtganesh/Documents/Pure/fe-home-loan/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Works fine after deleting MYFONT.ttf from the Project.

Project Specs

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17"
yarn version - 1.3.2
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your time. (:

Comment: that error is thrown when you have no space, try adding more space for your watcher.

Comment: @ReiDien as per the `df` command, my filesystem has only 34% used

Comment: watcher has own limitation, take nodemon as an example https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/214

Comment: it is not about your disk space, but your watcher space

Comment: @ReiDien How can I solve this for react-scripts?

Comment: cant help you with that as i have no interest in digging what react-script is

Comment: @ReiDien What ttf font file does with watcher space issue?

Comment: the script basically watches all files to restart the service when any changes happens

Comment: @ReiDien I can understand what watcher does. But I can't understand why it is interested in TTF font file to be deleted. I've made other changes and tried running and it doesn't work.

Comment: if it is watching the whole directory, any kind of change on any kind of file will be watched.